# jQuery - Unchecked radio buttons not returning a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For the life of me I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong, I have a basic form with a radio button and a text box. I'm trying to perform a basic validation so if I add a text area or select box in the future it will validate using **if($this).val() === '')** it works great for those but why not my radio buttons? When I try to alert the length I only get one alert message not two? Any help is greatly appreciated! JS Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/5Sacj/

```
<div class="two-column">
  <label id="gender" for="gender">Gender</label>
  <input type="radio" name="customer" value="male" />Male
  <input type="radio" name="customer" value="female" />Female
</div>

<div class="two-column">
  <label for="fname">*First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $(":text, :radio").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "")
     alert($(this).length);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for textboxes and radio buttons.

```
$(":text, :radio").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "" || !$(this).is(':checked'))
        alert($(this).length);
});
```

If you want it to work for textareas and all types of input, change your selector to:

```
$("input, textarea").each(function() {
   // same code
});
```

EDITED: http://jsfiddle.net/5Sacj/2

Comment: Thanks @MarloC but I want to validate multiple input types as well not just radio buttons. **if($(this).val() === "")** works for other form elements. Is there a general condition I can use that with apply to all?

Comment: Yes, there is! Hang on, let me create a fiddle for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of both radio items are already set.

```
<input type="radio" name="customer" value="male" />Male
<input type="radio" name="customer" value="female" />Female
```

If you change your JS to

`$(document).ready(function() {`

```
    $(":text, :radio").each(function() {

     alert($(this).length);
   });

});
```

You will get three popups.